# Reference native UI elements in test with vue 3 & vue test utils without adding attributes to a UI element

Tags: mocha.js, chai, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

Question: **How can you reference native UI elements in vue 3 and vue test utils without adding extra attributes to that UI element?**

When testing vue components with **vue 3** and **vue test utils**, I noticed that there wasn't really an elegant way to find UI elements. Since Vue 3, Vue Test Utils do not provide a way to use the ref attribute anymore on a native UI element like a button for example.

I know about these solutions:

```
<button data-test="button" ></button> or <button class="button"> </button>
```

But adding extra attributes or classes to the component just for the sake of testing the component doesn't feel like a solution. Also the error that the test throws is not very descriptive. For example when testing events  `Error: Cannot call trigger on an empty DOMWrapper.`